# ssh-agent stopped working after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: ssh, gnome-keyring, gnome-session

my ssh is asking for my keys everytime I try to log onto my servers, this is happening after I upgraded my ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10, before that it unlocked my keys at my session login, but now it's not working.

How can I reset the mechanism that takes care of my keys?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:
Solved with this two commands

```
gnome-keyring-daemon -s
ssh-add -D
```

Comment: Please don't put the solution/answer in your question, but post answers as answers.